# How to structure game dialogue?

Tags: javascript, html, object, tree

I'm working on a dialogue system for a small browser game. It was supposed to be a simple enough learning exercise but I'm drowning in objects/dialogue trees like

```
let example = {
  text: "example text",
  options: {
    one: {
      texto: "option one",
      options: {
        //etc etc etc
      }
    },
      two: "option two",
      options: {
        //on and on
     }
  }
}
```

What would be a better way to do this?

I'm looking for two things really: A more modular system to store and make the dialogue accessible and a way to link different dialogues in a particular scene.

something like this:

Text 1 **-->** select options from a pool of options linked to text 1 **-->** link every option to a specific new text.

New Text **-->** this text options **-->** this options linked to new text.

etc.

just clickable options that present new text with new clickable options.

Any examples I could check?

even just a push in the right direction would be of immense help.

Comment: Do you mean like this?
option A contains option A.1, option A.2, options A.3, option A.4 and so on...
Once user clicks on option A.1, Now:
option A.1 contains option A.1.1, option A.1.2, option A.1.3 and so on...

Comment: Exactly like that, I think. Each option should point to a text with options of its own.

Comment: Do you have any fixed level of nesting? or it can keep on increasing?

Comment: Nesting the dialogue is one of the things I'm trying to fix, because I already have like 100 levels and is a royal mess

Comment: yes agreed!
If there are like 100 levels, it is a real mess.
If you really want json object for such an info, I can only think as array of objects only.

A:[{
 A1:{
   A1.1 : {
    },
  A1.2 :{
   }
  }
}]

in a nested fashion\